# Stop YouTube tracking when signed out

Tags: privacy, javascript, cookies, google, user-tracking

I use YouTube while signed out. I have a Google account, but I only sign in to
check email, then sign right back out. YouTube is tracking what I watch when
signed out, then putting similar videos in the related videos part of the
sidebar.

I think they are using the `VISITOR_INFO1_LIVE` cookie to do this, but removing
the cookie only fixes the problem for a moment:

1. Remove cookie
2. Reload page
3. Related videos based on history are gone, only generic related videos remain
4. Reload page
5. Related videos based on history are back

I noticed that the cookie in question expires next year, could I use JavaScript
to expire it now? Or can I make this stop some other way? I saw
[this question](//security.stackexchange.com/q/65799), but I am not using the Flash player, I am using HTML5
player.

Comment: Maybe take a look at this option. https://superuser.com/questions/706690/is-it-possible-to-block-one-cookie-on-a-domain

Comment: you should block ALL 3rd party cookies anyway, very few sites "break" without them.

Comment: you need only to block all cookies under domaine **youtube.com** in addition to **youtube-nocookie.com**, that's what worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click <kbd>Pause watch history</kbd> and <kbd>Clear all watch history</kbd> here:

http://youtube.com/feed/history

Note that this page says:

> Watch History isn't viewable when signed out

but it still appears to fix the issue. Thanks to this answer:

http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/91603

Comment: This just stops Google from showing you the stuff - behind the scenes they are still tracking you.

Comment: @AndréBorie maybe I worded the question wrong then - I dont care if they track me as long as I cant tell they are

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe the above solutions work very effectively individually. What I have noticed is that even if I use a different browser, I still get the same video suggestions when I sign in elsewhere. I think in addition to the above options, they also use the IP address to associate you with the videos you watch. So far the best way I've found is to use a VPN while watching youtube. The drawback is the streaming speed of course.

Answer (score 1):

I also suggest using two different browsers; one for all signed-in work, and one for all not-signed-in work.  Regular use of "Clear all history" on *both* browsers, makes thing even better.  Most of the time, you only need your bookmarks, and those are not affected by "Clear all history".

I do use Privacy Badger also, on top of this arrangement, but this guards against any potential bugs in such tools, any other unexpected exposures, etc.

I've been doing this ever since I saw the panopticlick demo, many years ago.

The only inconvenience is copying links (say, sent in email to me, hence showing on the "signed-in" browser) manually using copy-paste to the not-signed-in browser to view.  That discipline takes time to cultivate but it's muscle memory for me now.  Combined with VimFX, Vimperator, or similar, it's not even very tedious.

Answer (score 0):

If the option provided by nd510 in the comments doesn't work, you could try more encompassing options like [Ghostery](https://www.ghostery.com/) or [Privacy Badger](https://www.eff.org/privacybadger) or any other of the many available browser-extensions that allow you to block cookies.

Of the two mentioned, Ghostery can be most easily tuned to block nothing except one specific cookie, while Privacy Badger is great for hassle-free blocking of everything that tracks you.

Answer (score 0):

Visit this [setting page on youtube](http://www.youtube.com/feed/history/search_history) to get to two options. You will actually have to change *2 settings.

First off, click on "pause search history" - this disables video logging.
Next, in the left menu, click "history" followed by the button at the top "pause viewing history". This will allow you to disable the recording of the videos that either you or someone you know watches on YouTube from your computer. It's really that simple.

Now, Should you decide that want to reenable video logging as well as historical video search history, you can undo the aforementioned settings simply by  clicking the "resume" buttons 2 times -  for both settings.

Comment: Do those work for even signed out users?

Answer (score -1):

Delete history every time before you want to sign in or out, doing this youtube won't know what type of videos you were watching before you connected to your account.

Or try using multiple Firefox profiles with different Youtube accounts, i tried this before and youtube didn't show me the same videos so i think they only track using cookies and not by using IP address.

Comment: Google still tracks even if you delete your history. It just doesn't show up in history. And yes, IP is a factor is what gets shown, but not a primary factor.